# Access denied to page when using hasPermission from Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my project, the methods from my controller have this structure:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="privado")
public class PrivadoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#usuario, 'admin_main')")
    public ModelAndView admin() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("privado/admin");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="customer")
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#usuario, 'customer_main')")
    public ModelAndView customer() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("privado/customer");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

The method hasPermission is implemented in this CustomPermissionEvaluator class:

```
@Component
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    public CustomPermissionEvaluator() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        System.out.println("CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission");
        if (arg0 == null || !arg0.isAuthenticated())
            return false;
        else
            return arg0.getAuthorities().contains(arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Serializable arg1, String arg2, Object arg3) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Id-based permission evaluation not currently supported.");
    }

}
```

My problem is, despite informing the right login credencials, and have the proper roles abd permissions for the user saved in the database, I am facing a default access denied page (and I have an custom page for this error in my project).

Anyone can see what I am doing wrong here?

ps.: the complete code for the security layer of my application can be found here:

https://github.com/klebermo/webapp2/tree/master/src/com/spring/webapp/lojavirtual/config/security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a more careful analysis in the code, I finally manage to solve this problem. It happens I am using the wrong argument in the method's body. The final code for my CustomPermissionEvaluator is:

```
@Component
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    public CustomPermissionEvaluator() {
    }

    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Object arg1) {
        System.out.println("CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission");
        System.out.println("arg0 = "+arg0);
        System.out.println("arg1 = "+arg1);

        if (arg0 == null || !arg0.isAuthenticated()) {
            System.out.println("false");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("true");
            for(GrantedAuthority authority: arg0.getAuthorities()) {
                if(authority.getAuthority().equals(arg1))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        System.out.println("CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission");
        System.out.println("arg0 = "+arg0);
        System.out.println("arg1 = "+arg1);
        System.out.println("arg2 = "+arg2);

        if (arg0 == null || !arg0.isAuthenticated()) {
            System.out.println("false");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("true");
            for(GrantedAuthority authority: arg0.getAuthorities()) {
                if(authority.getAuthority().equals(arg2))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Serializable arg1, String arg2, Object arg3) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Id-based permission evaluation not currently supported.");
    }

}
```